# iterated mel script from command by command

Tags: mel

I am trying to write a mel script that assigns a CV curve (with 5 knots) to each vertex on an animated object. For each vertex on the animated object the base of a single CV curve is then aligned using the constraints in order: geometry, normal (with length of CV curve aligned with normal direction), and point on poly. After this each of the CV curves are made dynamic in the nHair module, with the base anchored to the vertex on the animated object. I have been able to record the mel commands for a single instance of this but do to know how to repeat the same command for all vertices on the animated object

```
curve -d 3 -p 0 0 0 -p 0 1 0 -p 0 2 0 -p 0 3 0 -p 0 4 0 -p 0 5 0 -k 0 -k 0 -k 0 -k 1 -k 2 -k 3 -k 3 -k 3 ;
select -r pSphere1 ;
select -tgl curve1 ;
geometryConstraint -weight 1;
select -r pSphere1 ;
select -tgl curve1 ;
normalConstraint -weight 1 -aimVector 0 1 0 -upVector 0 1 0 -worldUpType "vector" -worldUpVector 0 1 0;
select -r pSphere1.vtx[184] ;
select -tgl curve1 ;
doCreatePointOnPolyConstraintArgList 2 {   "0" ,"0" ,"0" ,"1" ,"" ,"1" ,"0" ,"0" ,"0" ,"0" };
{string $constraint[]=`pointOnPolyConstraint -offset 0 0 0  -weight 1`; setAttr ($constraint[0]+".pSphere1U0") 0.200000; setAttr ($constraint[0]+".pSphere1V0") 0.500000;};
select -r curve1 ;
makeCurvesDynamic 2 { "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"};
select -r follicle1 ;
selectKey -clear ;
setAttr "follicleShape1.pointLock" 1;
```

[image: Screen Shot]

(great! can't embed an image yet as I haven't earned enough points...)

I know this is just a screengrab of the normals displayed on a sphere in Maya (if I was allowed to embed it - for now just turn normals display on for a sphere in Maya), but if you can imagine each normal line is actually a CV curve follicle then you can understand what I am trying to script - I want to be able to select all the vertices on the sphere and assign CVs which are then converted to dynamic follicles...